# Passing values of array to a function that modifies the value then returns it into a new array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers

I'm having trouble getting my code to return the correct arrays.  void map takes in a function such as tiple and modifies the value that was passed into it from the array src and then returns the new value into dst which is then printed out.  I can get the code to compile but it doesn't return the correct array. For example, when it takes in [1,2,3,4] it returns [0,3,6,9] instead of [3,6,9,12]

```
typedef int (*intModifier)(int);

int triple(int x){
    return 3*x;
}

void map(intModifier func, int src[], int dst[], int length){
    for(int *i = src; i < src + length; ++i){
    dst[*i] = func(*i);
    }
return;

}

void printIntArray(int arr[], int length){
cout << "{";
    if (length > 0){
    cout << arr[0];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < length; ++i){
    cout << ", " << arr[i];
    }
    cout << "}";
    }

int main(){

int arr1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int arr2[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int arr3[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int arr4[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

cout << "Testing map." << endl;
cout << "  setting arr1 = {1,2,3,4}" << endl << endl;

cout << "  mapping from arr1 to arr2 using triple" << endl;
map(triple, arr1, arr2, 4);
cout << "  arr2 = ";
printIntArray(arr2, 4);  cout << endl << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is `intModifier` a typedef, please show it. Also indent your code.

Comment: Also can you show how you are calling your function?

Comment: The `dst[*i] = func(*i)` assignment is  wrong.  You don't want to use *i as an index into dst, and in this case with {1,2,3,4} it's writing past the end of dst.  You'll need to use something else as an index in dst.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it is only the second element being modified. But the fact that is only one is almost definitely this:

```
void map(intModifier func, int src[], int dst[], int length){
    for(int *i = src; i < src + length; i++){
        dst[*i] = func(src[*i]);
        return; // You return here!!!
    }
}
```

You will always return from `map` during the first iteration of your `for` loop. See how beneficial it is to indent your code!

Comment: You also included the missing `}` from the for loop!

Comment: @KillaBytes Hmmm, it wasn't missing before the edit.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's still returning weird stuff.  Somehow it's pulling a 0 from src and putting it in the first spot followed by 1 2 3.  I also changed it to increment i before the loop but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MylesPollie - Could you update your code in the original post to match your changes? That way we can help you further.

Comment: @KillaBytes - Alright it's all updated.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` function is what is causing most of the issues. Especially in the way you are trying to conduct the operations in the `for` loop.

```
void map(intModifier func, int src[], int dst[], int length){
    for(int *i = src; i < src + length; ++i){ // There are some major issues in how you are 
        dst[*i] = func(*i);                   // iterating through the source array.
    }
return;

}
```

You are using the value of the source array to increment and store data between your destination array and source array. Your arrays are only 4 int "blocks" yet you increment through source at the source base length plus 4 `i < src + length` which is going well past your array length.

It would be better if you iterate through using the length you pass in, that's essentially why you pass the length in correct? So you could use this:

```
void map(intModifier func, int src[], int dst[], int length){

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // Iterate until we have met the length of the source
    {                                // array. Pass the source array off to our triple func
        dst[i] = func(src[i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

The function iterates through source and passes its contents to the `triple` func then stores it at the same location in our destination array.

EDIT: Credit given to *1201ProgramAlarm* and *Ben*.